Loading a raster from Leaflet into QGIS
I'm trying to do what's supposed to be the simplest thing - loading a WMS layer of the raster data from the resource http://ikcest-drr.osgeo.cn/map/m021f into QGIS - to no avail. I've been using different variations of the following link: https://tile.osgeo.cn/service?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=mp021f&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=10018754.171394622,2504688.542848655,12523442.714243278,5009377.085697314, only to get messages about how it can't load data from the server.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Read https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wms.html . Edit the question to add the full error messages from qgis.
